# How do I upgrade an existing EDMX 1.0 model to the new EDMX 2.0?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, edmx

I'd like to upgrade an existing EDMX model without having to regenerate it by hand. The database is old, contains virtually no foreign keys and has many tables that had to be merged into single entities. I would like to use the EDMX 2.0 that comes with Visual Studio 2010, but I **do not** want to recreate the model by hand as that would put us way behind schedule.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your old project in VS 2010. Then just change Target Framework from 3.5 to 4.0 in your project settings. In this case the .edmx file will be updated automatically.